# How does $Ae^{4ix}+Be^{-4ix}=A\cos(4x)+B\sin(4x)$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$

$Ae^{4ix}=A(\cos(4x)+i\sin(4x))$

$Be^{-4ix}=B(-\cos(4x)-i\sin(4x))$

What am I doing wrong?

> I am trying to find the complimentary function of $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} +16y=8cos(4x)$
>
> C.F: $x^2+16=0$
>
> $x=4i$ and $x=-4i$
>
> $$Ae^{4ix}+Be^{-4ix}$$

$\phi\pm\beta i$

$$\Rightarrow e^{\phi x}(Asin\beta x+Bcos\beta x) $$

Comment: OK, what they meant to say (and perhaps did say) was that: a function can be written in the form $Ae^{4ix}+Be^{-4ix}$ for some constants $A,B$ if and only if it can be written in the form $A\cos(4x)+B\sin(4x)$ for some constants $A,B$.  Of course the values $A,B$ are not the same in the two cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get $Be^{-4ix}=B(\cos(-4x)+i\sin(-4x))=B(\cos(4x)-i\sin(4x))$ since $\cos(-a)=\cos a$ and $\sin(-a)=-\sin a$.

By adding
$Ae^{4ix}=A(\cos(4x)+i\sin(4x))$ and
$Be^{-4ix}=B(\cos(4x)-i\sin(4x))$
you get
$$Ae^{4ix}+Be^{-4ix}=(A+B)\cos(4x)+i(A-B)\sin(4x).$$

---

EDIT: (Now that you have added that you were asking because solving a differential equation.)

We have expressed $Ae^{4ix}+Be^{-4ix}$ in the form $C\cos 4x+D\sin 4x$. Notice that we can get arbitrary $C,D\in\mathbb C$ (by choosing appropriate $A$, $B$.) So we have $y(x)=C\cos 4x+D\sin 4x$ as a general solution of $y''+16y=0$.

EDIT 2: To be more precise: For any given $C$, $D$ we can find $A$ and $B$ such that $A+B=C$, $i(A-B)=D$ by solving the system of two linear equations. Namely we get $B=(C+iD)/2$ and $A=(C-iD)/2$.

Basically the thing I am trying to get is explained in different words in [kahen's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409179/how-does-ae4ixbe-4ix-a-cos4xb-sin4x/409184?noredirect=1#comment875881_409187).

Comment: Which is not $A\cos(4x)+B\sin(4x)$?

Comment: Which is not $A\cos(4x)+B\sin(4x)$. It was already pointed out in [Abhra Abir Kundu's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/409183/) that this can't be true. John suggested in [his answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/409187/) that the problem might be just the sloppy notation of whoever wrote that equality.

Comment: I didn't mean that in a rude way!! In an observed way! I have explained how the question came about in my question. Can you have a look?

Comment: I've already edited my answer as a reaction to the information you have added to your post. (And was not trying to imply that you were being rude. Sorry if that sounded like that.)

Comment: Haha, I just thought my comment looked a bit rude! I don't really understand your new answer. Surely there is a formula like De Moivres theorem?

Comment: In the addition to my answer I was trying to explain that you in fact get linear combinations of $\cos4x$ and $\sin4x$ in this way. It does not matter too much whether the constants are denoted by A, B or by C, D. But of course, if you have been taught to do this differently, simply try to do it your way and do not let my answer confuse you.

Answer (score 3):

Well in the third line the negative sign should actually be part of the argument of the trigonometric functions but in answer to the larger question, I would say that the A and B on the left hand side are not the same as the A and B on the right hand side but rather two new complex constants (that will depend on the old A and B). This is a bit sloppy notation but some people do it.

Comment: What it's saying is that $\def\span{\operatorname{span}}V = \{x\mapsto Ae^{i4x} + Be^{-i4x} \mid A,B \in \mathbb C \land A = \bar B\} \subset \span_{\mathbb C}\{x\mapsto e^{i4x},x\mapsto e^{-i4x}\}$ and $W = \span_{\mathbb R}\{x \mapsto \sin(4x), x \mapsto \cos(4x)\}$ are equal.

Comment: ahh the OP has edited since I posted this. I thought this may have been the situation problem would came up in. The important thing is that you get some amount of sines and some amount of cosines. In order to give a general solution on either side, we need two constants and I would say they've just used A and B for each expression. Both sides give the same general solution.

Comment: @john So you are literally supposed to just take an educated guess? (there is no formula) I hate that.

Comment: Oh no, there are several formulas for solving differential equations. In this case after solving the corresponding polynomial since the roots are imaginary i.e. $\alpha \pm \beta i$ with $\alpha =0, \beta = 4$ the general solution to the homogeneous equation would have been $A e^{\alpha x} \sin (\beta x) + A e^{\alpha x} \cos (\beta x)$ which gives the desired result or you can do it your way with with the complex exponentials and then expand and redefine your constants.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in $Be^{-4i x} = B(\cos(-4x)+i\sin(-4x)) = B(\cos(4x)-i\sin(4x))$.

Comment: but $\cos(-\theta)=\cos \theta$

Comment: Oops, I wrote it the wrong way around. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true

for $x=0$ we have $A+B= A$ which is not true in general.

Answer (score 1):

$Be^{-4ix}=B(\cos(-4x)+i\sin(-4x))=B(\cos 4x-i\sin4x)$